# UdpClient vs TcpClient

Tags: c#, .net

what is the difference between UdpClient and TcpClient ? When should i use Tcp and when Udp from the point of software arhitecture ? I hope i've explained it right ..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically,

- UDP is faster than TCP because packets are sent without guarantee of delivery nor order
- TCP is safer, because each packet is acknowledged and ordered

You should have a read at those links :

- [UDP vs TCP, how much faster is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903/udp-vs-tcp-how-much-faster-is-it)
- http://www.skullbox.net/tcpudp.php (short)
- http://www.laynetworks.com/Comparative%20analysis_TCP%20Vs%20UDP.htm (long)

Answer (score 18):

TCP vs UDP comparison - Usage

- TCP is used in case of non-time critical applications.
- UDP is used for games or applications that require fast transmission of data. UDP's stateless nature is also useful for servers that answer small queries from huge numbers of clients.

TCP vs UDP comparison - Function

- As a message makes its way across the internet from one computer to another. This is connection based.
- UDP is also a protocol used in message transport or transfer. This is not connection based which means that one program can send a load of packets to another and that would be the end of the relationship.

TCP vs UDP comparison - Acronym for

- Transmission Control Protocol
- User Datagram Protocol or Universal Datagram Protocol

TCP vs UDP comparison - Weight

- TCP requires three packets to set up a socket connection, before any user data can be sent. TCP handles reliability and congestion control.
- UDP is lightweight. There is no ordering of messages, no tracking connections, etc. It is a small transport layer designed on top of IP.

TCP vs UDP comparison - Streaming of data

- Data is read as a byte stream, no distinguishing indications are transmitted to signal message (segment) boundaries.
- Packets are sent individually and are checked for integrity only if they arrive. Packets have definite boundaries which are honored upon receipt, meaning a read operation at the receiver socket will yield an entire message as it was originally sent.

TCP vs UDP comparison - Speed of transfer

- The speed for TCP in comparison with UDP is slower.
- UDP is faster because there is no error-checking for packets.

TCP vs UDP comparison - Examples

- HTTP, HTTPs, FTP, SMTP Telnet etc...
- DNS, DHCP, TFTP, SNMP, RIP, VOIP etc...

TCP vs UDP comparison - Data Reliability

- There is absolute guarantee that the data transferred remains intact and arrives in the same order in which it was sent.
- There is no guarantee that the messages or packets sent would reach at all.

TCP vs UDP comparison - Connection Reliable

- Two way Connection reliable
- one way Connection Reliable

TCP vs UDP comparison - Ordering

- TCP rearranges data packets in the order specified.
- UDP does not order packets. If ordering is required, it has to be managed by the application layer.

TCP vs UDP comparison - Error Checking

- TCP does error checking
- UDP does not have an option for error checking.

TCP vs UDP comparison - Header Size

- TCP header size is 20 bytes
- UDP Header size is 8 bytes.

[Short compare.](http://www.diffen.com/difference/TCP_vs_UDP)
[Must have book.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132126958)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: +1 for the book, Tanembum et.al. is definitely one of the three must have books for any developer (the others being the dragon book on compilers and the dinosaur book on operating systems).

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: here is to you.

Answer (score 2):

[UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) and [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) are two different protocols.

Basicly, you almost always want to use TCP unless you have a very compelling reason not to.

UDP is a very basic protocol on top of the IP protocol, and only adds simple checks if the data isn't corrupt.

TCP on the other hand is much more complicated, but also much more reliable, because it guarantees that you're data arrives, arrives in the right order and things like congestion control.

Answer (score 1):

To sum it up TCP where you do not want lost data(resend data) Real-time live streaming like video we do not want lost packets resent it is real-time so use  UDP

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, try to provide more information and examples where possible. That way you will earn more points.