# Does http protocol have a limit on body size

Tags: javascript, html, http

I'm wondering if http protocol has a limit on body size. For example, if I want to send a file from server of 1Tb, is this possible? This is hypothetical situation with a file like that, just an example

My question is about restrictions imposed by the protocol, not the server. And I'm talking about the response body, not the request.

Comment: Of course it is. It would take a while, though. Just increase the timeout

Comment: It ultimately depends on the server implementation - for example, IIS7 has a hard limit of 30MB by default. You *probably* wouldn't want to upload a 1TB through the HTTP protocol. You may find better luck using [rsync or FTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707900/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-transfer-files-over-a-network-ftp-http-rsync-etc). Your absolute best bet would definitely be to use some kind of streaming approach, though

Comment: @ARedHerring "IIS7 has a hard limit of 30MB" That's not true. The default value for the server is 30Mb but it can be changed in the config files (on [server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942074) or [site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462(v=vs.90).aspx) level)

Comment: @Andreas You seem to have missed the words "by default" after the part you're quoting me on.

Comment: There is no limit defined in the protocol and it is very unlikely that any server has an issue delivering such a bigger payload. However I would expect most clients to have issues with that.

Comment: @arkascha, thanks. Do you know any approchs where such big files are delivered with several http responses?

Comment: Certainly one could split a big payload into smaller chunks, but that is questionable. Especially since that does _not_ allow to use standard clients for the task, since the client would have to recombine the chunks into the original payload. So it would require special code. I am not aware that such approaches are implemented in mainstream. As others mentioned: it might make more sense to look for another, more suitable protocol.

Comment: @arkascha, thanks a lot, you've answer my question perfectly. Put your comments as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Your wish is my command :-) Have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit defined in the protocol and it is very unlikely that any server has an issue delivering such a bigger payload. However I would expect most clients to have issues with that.

Certainly one could split a big payload into smaller chunks to use multiple http requests, but that is questionable. Especially since that does not allow to use standard clients for the task, since the client would have to recombine the chunks into the original payload. So it would require special code. I am not aware that such approaches are implemented in mainstream. As others mentioned: it might make more sense to look for another, more suitable protocol.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a limit. However, in Apache you can set a limit by means of the LimitRequestBody directive which is set to zero (unlimited) by default.

Comment: thanks, I'm more interested in server response, so server configuration on requests makes no difference