# Does WiFi support UDP and TCP (Android device)

Tags: android, networking, tcp, udp

I've been looking around and I have found that there is evidence that Android can use UDP with it's WiFi, but can TCP be used? I know it probably can, but I can't seem to find any evidence, looking at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html it doesn't say anything about the protocol it can use,

Does anyone have a website that states what protocols can be used, and also, I'm createing an application for android where multiple users can connect to one WiFI hotspot device and they can all play together and be real time networking, I feel UDP would be best, do you agree?

Canvas

Comment: UDP is best for gaming. As it has low over head of data.

Comment: Indeed true, but I need to gather some resources that state this :)

Comment: Here is more about it :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903/udp-vs-tcp-how-much-faster-is-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP, TCP and much more network stuff is placed under java.net location 
and can be found here

[java.net in android api](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

TCP is possible I know for sure, because I've used it.

That being said I do not have any any link to a resource that states as much.

I can tell you that in order to implement it on Android I used the `Socket` class along with some Input/Output streams.

Comment: Ok cheers, I just need to document stuff, and I don't really want to say, I'm UDP because it's better for games, I need to try and show abit of understanding on why :), but I think the better question is, does WiFi support UDP and TCP/IP because Android just uses the WiFi chip, so the question title i feel maybe abit wrong now :(