# J2ME UDP slower than TCP

Tags: tcp, java-me, udp, comparison, gprs

I'm developing a client/server based system using two GPRS modems (Siemens TC65).  The application sends relatively small frames (128 bytes each) from the client to the server and vice versa. Initially I used an UDP connection (using UDPDatagramConnection), but then I decided to change to a TCP connection (using SocketConnection and ServerSocketConnection) and compared the delay between the two.

I did 40 tests around 4 seconds apart from each other measured the round-trip time using the exact same application (just changing the connection method) at the same time of the day to ensure the traffic was similar, surprisingly I got the following results:

[image: TCP / UDP comparison results]

I was expecting that UDP would be faster but TCP is on average two times faster than UDP. I'm having trouble justifying this. I read threads like this one
[UDP vs TCP, how much faster is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903/udp-vs-tcp-how-much-faster-is-it) 
and they helped but I'm not sure the Neagle's algorithm has anything to do with it since I waited for every frame to arrive before sending the next frame.

I would apreacite any tips justifying these results.
Also is there any influence by doing the connection under GPRS?

Comment: I believe the main advantage of using UDP is to be asynchronous. Fire all your events at once and count the time until the last response arrives.

Comment: I actually tried that, that was the main reason for me to change to TCP cause if I sent frame too quickly, they took increasingly more time to arrive and eventually were dropped. I mean the first 3 took around 4~5 secs then 10, 30, 4 minutes, and so on. I'm sure TCP  works better due to the Neagle's algorithm.