# C++ Gaming application UDP vs TCP

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp, udp

I am making a real time application. I can't say much about it, but it's an online real time application that needs as little latency as possible. I am using sockets, no library. Also I need full bandwitdh. Should I use TCP or UDP? I don't mind programming a bit more to get UDP working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: actually answer here - use both, udp for not important updates, tcp for important ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the nature of client connections.

TCP is stateful session. If you have a lot of clients connected at the same time, you may suffer port exhaustion. If clients connect and disconnect frequently, establishing and tearing down TCP session adds to latency, CPU load and bandwidth. If your client connections are more or less permanent and not too many clients are connected at the same time, TCP is only slightly worse than UDP.

UDP is much better suited for low-latency communications. Beware of NAT firewalls however - not all are capable or are set up for UDP address mapping.

Also be aware that TCP is a stream and, as such, does not provide message packetization. Your application has to assemble packets from TCP stream with additional overhead.

UDP is by definition a complete message, i.e. arrives as a packet that was sent. Beware that delivery is not guaranteed and application may need to provide acknowledgement and resending layer.

Answer (score 0):

TCP/IP implements a stream; that is, it wants to send the recipient everything sent through it on the other end.  To this end, it adds a lot of protocol that handles situations where a portion of the stream is missing--such that it will retry sends, keep track of how many bytes it still needs to send (with a window), etc.  The TCP/IP connection is used to add the guarantee of the streams; if TCP/IP fails to deliver packets and cannot recover, the connection will drop.

UDP/IP implements a datagram--that is, it wants to send a particular packet (with a small limited size) from A to B.  If a datagram is lost, there's no built in way to resend it.  If it's not lost, UDP packets are just dropped.

The UDP lack of guarantees is actually a benefit.  Say you're modeling something like "health"--a monster attacks you twice on a server.  Your health drops from 90 to 78, then to 60.  Using TCP/IP, you must receive 78 first--so if that packet was dropped, it has to be resent, and in order--because there's a stream here.  But you really don't care--your health now is 60; you want to try to get 60 across.  If 78 was dropped by the time your health reaches 60, who cares--78's old history and not important any more.  You need health to say 60.

TCP is also a benefit--you don't want to use UDP for in game chats.  You want everything said to you to come to you, in order.

TCP also adds congestion control; with UDP you'd have to implement it, or somehow take care that you throttle UDP such that it doesn't saturate the unknown network characteristics between the server and the player.

So yes, you want to use "both"; but "importance" isn't quite the criteria you need to aim for.  Use TCP/IP for delivering streams, easy congestion control, etc.  Use UDP for real time states, and other situations where the stream abstraction interferes with the purpose rather than aligning with it.

Answer (score 0):

Both UDP and TCP have benefits in terms of latency. If all of the below is true:

- You have a single source of data in your client
- Send small messages but are worried about their latency
- Your application can deal with loosing messages from time to time
- Your application can deal with receiving messages out of order

UDP may be a better option. Also UDP is good for sending data to multiple recipiemts.

On the other hand, if either

- If any of the above is not true
- If your application sends as much data as possible as fast as possible
- You have multiple connections to maintain

You should definitely use TCP.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903/udp-vs-tcp-how-much-faster-is-it) will tell you why UDP is not necessarily the fastest.

If you are planning to tranfer large quantity of data over TCP, you should consider the effect of [bandwidth delay product](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth-delay_product). Although you seem to be more worried about the latency than throughput, it may be of an interest to you.