# UDP Server in Python

Tags: python, windows, sockets, networking, python-3.x

How can I create a UDP server in Python that is possible to know when a client has disconnected? The server needs to be fast because I will use in an MMORPG. Never did a UDP server then I have a little trouble.

Comment: Are you asking whether a Python UDP server is faster than a Python TCP server? And you need to know when a client disconnects? Please edit your question to make it clearer for us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a connection in UDP. Because of this, it becomes your responsibility to detect if the client has disconnected. Generally speaking, your protocol should implement a way to notify the server that it is ending its session. Additionally, you will need to implement some type of timeout functionality such that after a certain period of interactivity, the session is ended.

Note that UDP is more difficult to work with than TCP because packets are not always guaranteed to be delivered. Depending on what you are doing, you might need to implement some type of check to ensure that packets that are not delivered are sent again. TCP does this for you, but it also has the side effect of making the protocol slower.

This answer provides some more considerations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57489/4250606

Answer (score 0):

UDP is not connection-based.  Since no connection exists when using UDP, there is nothing to disconnect.  Since there is nothing to disconnect, you can't ever know when something disconnects.  It never will because it was never connected in the first place.