# Is it normal that UDP is about a hundred times faster than TCP?

Tags: c#, tcp, udp

I just implemented both tcp and udp for sending some datagrams. When sending 10mb of those datagrams, the sending on udp is finished in 1 seconds and it cost me 3 extra mb in resends for packet loss.

With tcp it took 30 seconds at about 5 mb overhead.

Is this expected behavior, or did I probably mess up the tcp implementation somewhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UDP vs TCP, how much faster is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903/udp-vs-tcp-how-much-faster-is-it)

Comment: 30 seconds is alot. How does cwnd behave? What is the round-trip-time? Are you sending over wifi?